# Why does DateTime.Now sets the highest bit in DateTime's usual binary representation?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

As far as I know, the binary representation of `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` structures are 8-byte numbers of ticks (1 millisecond = 10000 ticks according to `TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond`). And values of Days, Hours, Minutes, etc. properties are obtained by integer division on `TicksPerDay`, `TicksPerHour`, `TicksPerSecond` etc. constants of `TimeSpan`.

For example if You run this code:

```
TimeSpan s1     = new TimeSpan(3, 5, 7, 9, 11).AddTicks(13));
long t1         = s1.Ticks;
```

You can get (if you use Visual Studio) something like that in you Memory windows:

```
0x061BE4D0  3d 2a c9 67 86 02 00 00
0x061BE4E0  3d 2a c9 67 86 02 00 00
```

where `0x061BE4D0` and `0x061BE4E0` are addresses of `s1` and `t1` respectively.
(Actually You should write '`s1`' and '`&t1`' instead of just '`t1`' in Address area of Memory window)

Now if You run another snippet of code:

```
DateTime d1     = new DateTime(1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11).AddTicks(13);
long t1         = d1.Ticks;

DateTime d2     = DateTime.Now;
long t2         = d2.Ticks;
```

You'll see for '`d1`', '`&t1`', '`d2`', '`&t2`' respectively the data like shown:

```
0x061AE438  3d 6a 5f 3d bd 01 00 00
0x061AE430  3d 6a 5f 3d bd 01 00 00 
0x061AE424  bd 71 d5 02 3f 9d d0 88
0x061AE41C  bd 71 d5 02 3f 9d d0 08
```

Why does `DateTime.Now` set the highest bit (0x 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00) in its binary representation?

Comment: The highest bit appears to me to be zero: You are looking at the _address_ of `t2` with `&t2`, not the _value_.

Comment: Highest bit of what? - DateTime.Now or DateTime.Now.Ticks? Yes, I know, it is strange but when you just put down 't2' it shows you weird bytes. And if you don't believe me (using VS2012) you must try repeat the same on your own to see that it is strange but it is

Comment: Because DateTime.Now has many ticks compared to your timespan. Your timespan only has few days, but Now has 2013 years of ticks, calculate how many seconds it has & how many ticks it has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the source code here (not sure exactly which version this is, but you get the idea):

http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/DateTime@cs/1/DateTime@cs

you can see that high bits are applied depending on whether the time is local or not.

From a quick glance over the code, there's a const member called:

```
private const UInt64 KindLocal             = 0x8000000000000000;
```

which looks as if it's used in the conversion. I'd suspect this is happening because you're using DateTime.Now, which is a local 'Now'. If you used 'UtcNow' it probably would set a different bit.

```
private const UInt64 KindUtc             = 0x4000000000000000;
```

However, when you get it as 'ticks', it probably returns the unspecified form, which has no top bit set.

```
private const UInt64 KindUnspecified       = 0x0000000000000000;
```

Basically, you're getting hung up on the inner workings of the struct. If you really want to understand it, then I'd suggest digging through the code. Otherwise, just use it as per the instructions, and it'll work fine for you!

Comment: There's a fourth kind as well - but it's hidden: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/05/02/more-fun-with-datetime.aspx

Comment: @Jon: Great article, thanks for posting. Interesting question, and prompted me dig into the code for a type I hadn't investigated before :) (Btw, just got your book in the post a few days back. Thoroughly enjoying it.)

Comment: Thank you! Your fully answered my question

Comment: @Baldrick, I asked that question because I needed some extension methods for byte[], DateTime, TimeSpan: GetTimeSpan(), GetBytes(), GetDateTime(), GetBytes(). I realized 'em like that: http://pastebin.com/MjR1WLzk - now i use 0x3fFFffFFffFFffFF instead of 0x7fFFffFFffFFffFF